# Allocation of disk space to new created databases in production

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds, disk-space

Our current production database has total disk space of 2 TB. (SQL Serve 2012 standard RTM version.)

Currently we have database size allocation as attached. Apart from FUNDSDB and DBAdmin, remaining are system created:

[image: Total databases and their size]

Can anyone suggest is it possible to reduce or shrink the size from the FUNDSDB database, which is our current production DB, and allocate it to a newly created database if, in future, we want to create any new database on the same instance? If not, what's the best possible alternative way to do it.

For example, if we want to allocate, like, 400 GB to the new database whereas our current prod db is holding 856 GB approx.

Comment: How much free space do the database files have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question is not clear what do you mean by saying

> Our current production database has total disk space of 2 TB

From the picture attached I see that all your databases use less than `1Gb` of space so I think you meant that your total disk space is `2Gb`, so you actually has enough space to allocate new db of `400Gb` size.

So first check disk space available by executing

```
exec xp_fixeddrives
```

If you have enough space (I don't know if there is something else on the same disk, you wrote here only about databases located on `D:`) just execute `CREATE DATABASE` command with appropriate db name and paths:

```
CREATE DATABASE NewDB
ON 
( NAME = 'NewDB_data',
    FILENAME = '...NewDB_data.mdf',
    SIZE = 409600MB) -- 400Gb
LOG ON
( NAME = 'NewDB_log',
    FILENAME = 'NewDB_log.ldf',
    SIZE = 1024MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 100MB ) ;
GO
```

---

> Can anyone suggest is it possible to reduce or shrink the size from
>   the FUNDSDB Database

This depends on how much free space there is in your database. You can find free space this way:

```
use FUNDSB;
exec sp_spaceused;
```